# Generate a Java REST proxy for a WCF service

Tags: java, android, json, wcf, rest

I'm working on an Android client for a WCF web service. I must generate the client proxy, and I need that it makes REST requests and handles REST responses. My web service exposes a JSON endpoint:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="TRISUser.UserServiceBehavior"
    name="TRISUser.UserService">
    <endpoint address="JSON" behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="RESTEP"
      contract="TRISUser.IUserService" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TRISUser.IUserService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

I'm trying to generate the code with the wsimport tool contained in the JDK. The question is: exposing a JSON endpoint is sufficient to make and handle JSON request/responses or I have to use another tool?

Comment: Rest services do not describe themselves. `wsimport` generates JAX-WS artifacts.

Comment: I'm not understanding. Are you saying "there isn't a way", or "that's not the way"?

Comment: Well there is a way to describe a REST service through a [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language), but most services do not do that since WADL is not widely accepted. `wsimport` is used on WSDL files which are based on SOA and not ROA. They define services and not resources. You can invoke the REST service with a HTTP client and a serialization / deserialization library (like gson) or use a REST client library like `Restlet`.

Comment: So there are no chances I can make a RESTful client proxy, right? Sorry, but I'm almost a novice in web services, and this information is fundamental for the client I'm developing.

Comment: [You can still do it](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) if you write a java interface that describes the REST service. I hesitated to recommend that since your service was in WCF.

Comment: I have no choices, I can't simply throw away WCF.